# Failure warning in Codeigniter when trying to use "PRINT" SQL statement on Stored Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

When using "PRINT" SQL statement I get an error on CodeIgniter when I try to call Stored Procedure.

I solved this by deleting that "PRINT" statement on SQL code, but there a lot of problems when someone else edit the Stored Procedure and put some "PRINT" on it.

This is my codeigniter code:

```
public function ModelSPCall($parameter1, $parameter2){
    $sp  = "EXEC ModelSPCall '$parameter1','$parameter2';";
    $res = $this->db->query($sp);
    if($res){
        return $res->result();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This cause the problem on SQL Stored Procedure:

```
PRINT('Some text')
```

This is the error that it cause.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 01000/0
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Some text
```

Comment: You have a problem, you know the answer, so what's the question?

Comment: Print should not be used to communicate with the "calling" application/code. It is acceptable for development purposes but most applications are not designed / coded to handle the output generated by print. Go talk to "someone else". Use source control. Discuss this with your team or management.

Comment: The question is because this Stored Procedures is shared with C# developers, and there are a lot of problems when them all comment their SQL code. My question goes for a probable solution to handle with it on Codeigniter. 

Anyways thanks @SMor, but I really want to know if there is a solution for it, I don't want more early morning calls when system fails.

Comment: Thanks SMor, that's true

Comment: And, there is no way to solve this? I got a problem again by new DB area's main guy.